# Deleting widget from list from a press within the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of custom TextFormField's that i added to them a delete icon
all I am trying to do is when I press the delete button it will be deleted from the list and the view

i tried adding a function to my form field with no success

I think my approach isn't the best way to implement what i want, I am open to any idea

here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
typedef DeleteCallback = void Function(Key key);

class DynamicFormField extends  FormField<String>{
  DynamicFormField({
    Key key,
    FormFieldSetter<String> onSaved,
    FormFieldValidator<String> validator,
    String initialValue = "",
    bool autovalidate = false,
    DeleteCallback onDelete(Key key),
  }) : super(
    onSaved: onSaved,
    validator: validator,
    initialValue: initialValue,
    autovalidate: autovalidate,
    builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
      return  Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 5,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter Player Name',
        ),
                onSaved: onSaved,
                validator: validator,
                initialValue: initialValue,
                autovalidate: autovalidate,

                ),
            ),
            IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
            onPressed: onDelete(key)
          ),
          ],
      );
    }
  );
}
```

```
DynamicFormField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
        onSaved: (input) => {players.add(Player(input))},
        onDelete: f,
      ),
    );
  }
  void f(Key key){
      fields.removeWhere((item) => item.key == key);
  }
```

tnx

Comment: I think there is some missing information here. I can't tell how fields variable is involved in the DynamicFormField construction. From the current code, I would say there is no link between the key you are trying to delete and any fields.item. Maybe you should pass key: item.key instead of UniqueKey() (which generates a new key each time) to DynamicFormField. Hope that helps

Comment: In order to see changes in your widget you need to redraw the widget. To trigger redraw function you need to add fields into widget's state and when delete is called, simply do `setState(() => fields.removeWhere((item) => item.key == key))` (or even better - `setState(() => fields = fields.filter((item) => item.key == key))`)

Comment: That what i did my problem is that f isn't compiling...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using ListView builder

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rummy/models/player.dart';
import 'package:rummy/screens/game_screen.dart';

class NewGame extends StatefulWidget {
  NewGame({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NewGameState createState() => _NewGameState();
}

class _NewGameState extends State<NewGame> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<Widget> fields;
  List<Player> players;
  _NewGameState() {
    players = new List<Player>();
    fields = new List();
    print(players);
    fields.add(generateField());
  }
  Widget generateField() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Enter Player Name',
      ),
      onSaved: (input) => {players.add(Player(input))},
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter some text';
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          child: Builder(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: fields.length,
                                itemBuilder:
                                    (BuildContext context, int postion) {
                                  return Row(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: fields[postion],
                                      ),
                                      IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
                                          onPressed: () => {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  print(postion);
                                                  fields.removeAt(postion);
                                                })
                                              }),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("asdasd");
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        players.clear();
                        _formKey.currentState.save();
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => GameScreen(players),
                            ));
                      } else
                        print(_formKey.currentState.validate());
                    },
                    child: Text('Submit'),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        fields.add(generateField());
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text('Add New Player'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used this 
https://github.com/MobMaxime/Flutter-To-Do-App/blob/master/lib/screens/todo_list.dart